# Scale Image by using FFT

Tags: image-processing, fft, 2d

Can we change the scale of image by using FFT? I mean, how should i do process on frequency domain of image to upscale or downscale the orginal image?

The other question of mine is that how can changing scale of image affect on fft of this image?

Comment: What do you mean by 'scale'? Resolution?

Comment: @Ixop yes, I mean upscaling or downscaling the resolution of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up-Scaling an image can be performed in the frequency-domain, as usual.

Given an image of $N \times M$, interpolation by integer factor $K$, using frequency-domain, is obtained by enlarging the $N \times M$-point FFT of the image into $K \cdot N \times K \cdot M$, where new FFT samples are all zero; except at the corners. After computing the inverse $K \cdot N \times K \cdot M$ - point DFT/FFT, the effect in the time-domain will be interpolation.

Comment: Where should i locate the zero pads in frequency domain?

Comment: as I said only the corner sub rectangles are nonzero, the rest is zero.